# How to bevel a sharp edge angle on a text mesh?

Tags: modeling, edges, bevel, intersection

When I try to bevel edges with sharp angles like this:
[image: 2 1]

It turns out like this:
[image: 2 2]

How can I avoid a jumbled mess as shown above without having to manually fix it in edit mode or use *Clamp Overlap* in the *Bevel* settings?

Comment: Maybe dissolve some vertical edges before bevelling in order to avoid intersecting faces?

Comment: just [remesh it to look like this](https://snipboard.io/EpraPo.jpg) and then you can easily bevel it

Comment: to add to moonboots' comment, your geometry is too dense. start with fewer vertices, that will mitigate the intersection problem. then the geometry can get denser and smoother again later with a subdivision modifier.

Comment: Or just wait for the new [bevel algorithm](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=16dpUQ57Xv8), but I've been waiting for a while…

Answer (score 4):

Start from a plane with evenly distributed vertices and faces filled around the number 2. Then select all faces and press <kbd>I</kbd> to [`Inset Faces`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/face/inset_faces.html) as deep as possible, don't mind the intersection as we will tackle that after. Press <kbd>NumPad-7</kbd> to go into Top View and just manually do a combination of moving, creating, deleting, and dissolving of vertices to make the faces distribute somewhat evenly and fill new quads. It doesn't have to be perfect. Then make sure you have no overlapping vertices by selecting everything with <kbd>A</kbd> then press <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge By Distance*. And then you can easily Bevel the Edge Loop nicely with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>.

[image]

[image]